# Directory to install Intel x86 Atom System Image

Tags: android-studio, intel-atom

I've downloaded Intel x86 Atom System Image from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86-29_r08-windows.zip but i do not know the directory to place the file

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this path:`${your sdk path}\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis`

If you dont know your android sdk path, you may open Android Studio, open `file-settings/preferences-appearance & behavior-system settings-Android sdk`, and you can find it .